# How to remove contours from the edge of the image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following image that I generate from the below script,

I would like to know how can I eliminate the contours from the borders? (i.e. between the black bg and the purple pixels).

You can find the image as a pytorch tensor [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J7VzRhjVcbgXb8JFEItwwMo8sAs24nEe/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
img = np.moveaxis(image.cpu().numpy(), 0, -1) # image is a pytorch tensor
img *= 255.0/img.max()
img = img.astype(np.uint8)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

_,t_img = cv2.threshold(img,90,155,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

c_img = cv2.Canny(t_img,10,100)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(c_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

drawContour = cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(255,0,0),1)
   
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Why don't you pad the image or threshold image with black before getting the contours so the figure is closed nicely. You can then  trim the image afterwards if you want.

Comment: @fmw42 I do threshold the image. Or could you explain it programmatically?

Comment: Pad your image with black all around (at least 1 pixel on all sides). See cv2.copyMakeBorder(). Then threshold your image. Then get your contours. They should then be continuous and not broken up by your edges of the image

Comment: You mean to eliminate contours at the edge between purple and black? Try to create a foreground mask and erode it by the estimated border size. Then test your contour's pixels and drop every contour that has points which are not in the foreground mask.

Comment: @Micka I would request you to explain it programmatically.

Comment: @fmw42 padding the image with  cv2.copyMakeBorder(). just made things worse. The border was created but while thresholding the contour at the edge (between black and purple) were still estimated.

Comment: Can you post original image?

Comment: @toyotaSupra please find the image tensor from the attached link

Comment: When I run your code on the image I get a different result. Are you sure the code above was used to generate the posted image?

Comment: And could you explain again what you want to accomplish? Do you just want to remove the 1px border between the black background and the foreground? What about the contours inside the colored foreground region?

Comment: @asdf Hi as mentioned, I want to remove the contour only at the image border i.e. (between black pixels and purple pixels)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know if this is what you want, but what you could do is: generate a binary mask of the foreground using either simple thresholding or masking black regions if the background is always black as seems to be the case here. Then you can erode the foreground mask to remove a defined amount of pixels from the border of the mask (side note: use `binary_dilation` for the opposite operation):

```py
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

# img should be a numpy array with RGB channels in the last dimension
fg_mask = (img > (0, 0, 0)).any(axis=-1)  # binary foreground mask (all pixels which are not black)
filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(fg_mask)  # fill potential holes in mask (not needed here)
eroded = ndimage.binary_erosion(filled,
                                iterations=1,
                                structure=ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, connectivity=2))
new_img = img * eroded[..., None]  # apply eroded mask to img
```

Parameters to adjust are `iterations` (the higher the value the more pixels are removed from the foreground/background border) and `structure` (`connectivity` of 1 delivers smoother edges, 2 is used here) of `binary_erosion`.

Results:

*Original picture*:

[image: Original picture]

*Processed picture (`new_img`) with eroded borders*:

[image: Processed picture (new_img)]